# Modifying data and log file properties using SMO

Tags: powershell

I have been trying to automate some of SQL Server's post-install configuration settings for a bunch of servers. One of the task is to change database files' default growth and growthtype from percent to KB/MB.

For the test, I'll just use a single instance and a test database. This is what I have come up with so far.

```
$sqlServer = "SQLSVRNM\INSTNM"

#Load SqlServer SMO assembly
[void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO")

#Connect to the instance using SMO
$smosvr = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server $sqlServer

#Filter database, assign db properties to variable
$database = $smosvr.databases | where name -eq "testdb"

#Check database size
$dbsize = $database.size

#Check database name
$name = $database.name

#Get logfile properties
$logfile = $database.logfiles

#Get logfile name
$logfileName = $logfile.filename

#Get file growth val
$logfileGrowth = $logfile.growth

#Get growthtype
$logfileGrowthtype = $logfile.growthtype

#Get logfile size 
$logfileSize = $logfile.size
```

When I set the new growth size using

```
$logfile.growth = [double](2.0 * 32.0)
```

I get the following error.

```
The property 'growth' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At line:1 char:1
+ $logfile.growth = [double](2.0 * 32.0)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException
```

But, if I do a get-member on $logfile, the properties exist.

```
$logfile | Get-Member -Name Growth*


TypeName: Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.LogFile

Name       MemberType Definition
----       ---------- ----------
Growth     Property   double Growth {get;set;}
GrowthType Property   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.FileGrowthType GrowthType {get;set;}
```

So, can someone help me understand what I might be missing here?
Thanks!

Comment: $logfile in your code is a collection.  Even if there's only one you have to break it out to set the properties.

Comment: Argh, that was it. Thanks.

Comment: Glad that helped.  I've posted my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$logfile in your code is a collection. Even if there's only one you have to break it out to set the properties